# Understanding the 2D discrete Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I just learned about the 1-dimensional discrete Fourier transform which got introduced to me by means of circulant matrices (in the context of convolutions) and noticing that they all have the same eigenvectors. Now I want to learn about the 2D Fourier transform but I couldn't find an explanation so far that satisfied me (most of them solely state the formula without deriving it), which is why I'm asking whether someone knows a good source where the 2D discrete Fourier transform gets properly derived/developed.

Comment: You could try to review a book about Optics, like "Fourier Optics" by J. Goodman.. the continuous version of the 2D Fourier Transform is important in Optics since the Far Field profile of a light beam is the 2D Fourier Transform of the incoming beam, as is also the profile that happens in the focal plane of a aspherical lens, so you could in practice to calculate and apply filters in the Fourier Plane doing calculations at speedlight because of this, also taking cross-correlations. In the same book, I believe is constructed the discrete case from the continuous case, to use it in simulations.

Comment: One can consider 2D Fourier transform as a sequence of two 1-dimensional discrete Fourier transforms: applied to the first variable and then to the second. The properties follow immediately. Not much new in the multidimensional case.

Answer (score 1):

I think any image processing course will introduce the 2-D DFT. It is hard to recommend anything in particular not knowing what you want to do with it, but:

- If you are interested in image processing oriented introduction, let me recommend this: [https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/ia/lect2.pdf](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Eaz/lectures/ia/lect2.pdf)
- If you want something a bit broader, I would start with this : https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoftaee261/chap8.pdf
- If you want something more theoretical and mathematical, .... then the relevant wikipedia pages are a good place to start in my opinion.

Comment: I have already found all the sources you mentioned (before asking this question I clearly did some research), but none of them really derive the 2D DFT but rather define it. Hence, I seek an explanation that introduces this topic by maybe approximating 2D functions with the respective 2D trig. functions.

Comment: I see. Sorry I could not be more helpful. Can you please pinpoint what is missing from e.g. the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform ?

Comment: Yes, I might go through all of the stated sources, I just hoped that someone on this platform might have a good recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend "Fouerier Analysis and its applications" by Gerald B. Folland. If you first want to take a look into the book (or can't afford it) you can find a photocopy of it as one of the first google entries when searching the title.